# Cannot enable PHP Filter module in a fresh Drupal 7 installation

Tags: 7, input-formats

In order to test my ISP (a2hosting.com), I created a simple website running Drupal version 7.74 (the latest from the 7 branch) on a subdomain. It is a standard installation, with no additional modules nor themes.

Then I tried to enable the PHP filter module. When clicking *Save configuration*, the admin/modules page reloads without giving any message and without enabling the module, which remains off. I can turn other modules on and off as expected, but not the PHP filter. Other features are apparently OK.

What could be the problem?

PS. I did this test after having problems with PHP code on my sites, as described on  [PHP content cannot be created or modified after ISP migration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/298330/php-content-cannot-be-created-or-modified-after-isp-migration). A2 support team was unable to help.

Comment: If enabling the module failed, then there is almost certainly an error message in your Drupal logs or your webserver logs even if nothing was shown on the screen. That error message will likely tell you what the problem was.

Comment: I can find messages about other modules being enabled or disabled, but Drupal's Recent log entries does not seem to report anything related to failed attempts to enable PHP filter. Where else in my webserver could I search?